# std::vector::erase(item) needs assignment operator to be defined for item?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, operators, stdvector

I have a class `C` which does not define `operator=`. I have am trying to use a vector like so: `std::vector<std::pair<C,D>> vec;`. Now, my problem is that I am not able to erase the pair after I am done with it. The compiler complains of missing `operator=` for `C`. Can I not have a vector of a class which does not have this operator? How do I get around this? I cannot add assignment to `C`. This is the error I get:

```
error C2582: 'operator =' function is unavailable in 'C'    C:\...\include\utility  196 1   my-lib
```

This is my code:

```
void Remove(const C& c) 
{
    auto i = cs_.begin();
    while( i != cs_.end()) {
        if (i->first == c) {
            cs_.erase(i);  // this is the problem
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
 }
```

where `cs_` is:

```
std::vector<std::pair<C,D>> cs_;
```

Comment: Post some code where you call erase

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that erase will reallocate your objects if you erase a different position than `std::vector::end()`. A reallocation implicates copying.

Notice that a vector of an uncopyable type is only partially useable. Before we had `emplace()` (pre-C++11) it was even impossible. If your class is however copyable, why dont you define an assignment operator then?

A workaround could be a vector of smartpointers (or normal pointers) like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<C>>`

Comment: Got it! I can't modify `C`. I guess assignment was not defined so that developers could not make copies but copy constructor was given so that it could be passed by value. Does that even make sense? I fixed the problem by using `std::list` instead of `std::vector`. I noticed though that the following does not work even with lists: `cs_.erase(std::remove_if(cs_.begin(), cs_.end(),
  [p] (std::pair<C,D> c) { return c.first == p;}),
         cs_.end());`

Comment: "If your class is however copyable, why dont you define an assignment operator then?" - Won't work if my class has const members or references which can be copied but not assigned.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. The standard requires that items in a vector or deque be *MoveAssignable* if `erase` is to work.

In general, vectors and deques need to be able to erase from arbitrary positions. When they do, they need to be able to shift any remaining items into the space vacated by the erased item. The standard says (or implies, anyway, by its *MoveAssignable* requirement on `erase`) that they do that by assigning, so the contained item needs an assignment operator. Another option *could* have been for the items to be copied as by the copy constructor, but that's not how it's done.

Comment: copy constructor is not an option because we already have existing objects

Comment: So destroy them, @Paranaix. Call the destructor, and then use placement new to copy the adjacent item into the vacated space.